# Eclipse PHP - How to make the comment styling agree with Doxygen

Tags: php, eclipse, doxygen

I'm using Doxygen with the Eclox plug in on Eclipse Helios for a PHP project.

Nearly everything is fine, BUT:

The Eclipse auto comment system generates the style:

`* @param typename $parametername`

...whereas Doxygen expects the opposite:

`* @param $parametername [typename]`

(Actually, Doxygen doesn't know about type names in PHP, as far as I can see - I just use the convention of making them the first word of the comment).

Not only does it mean I'm continually having to delete the "unknown_type" that Eclipse puts in, but it also uses the variable names from the comments in its outline generator (rather than the variable names in the code). So having set up all the comments to work well with Doxygen, my outline generator has lost all the parameter names.

Does anyone know how to set Eclipse/Eclox/Doxygen up differently?

Comment: I don't know where to change it, but Eclipse is probably expecting the [phpdoc](http://www.phpdoc.org/) format here.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is implemented in the recent releases of Doxygen. See https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=613185

@var and @return are still not supported.